# Convert HTML string to HTML and display in DIV

Tags: domparser

I have HTML string saved in data base , I want to display it into DIV in HTML format using javascript.
Example:

```
 <p>Dear Friends</p> <h1> You have got invitation </h1>
```

I have used DOMParser like this

```
parser = new DOMParser();
htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(document.getElementById(controlID).innerHTML, "text/html");
console.log(htmlDoc);
document.getElementById("emailBodyArea").innerHTML = parser
```

but in result I see [htmlObject]

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use any DOMParser just replace emailBodyArea innerHTML with controlId innerHTML or any string based HTML.

```
document.getElementById("emailBodyArea").innerHTML = document.getElementById(controlID).innerHTML;
```

You can try it on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jo6xdgwv/12/).

Comment: I did the same but I do not know, why the code you suggested giving the same result i.e. showing HTML tags

Comment: Problem solved . document.getElementById("emailBodyArea").innerHTML = document.getElementById(controlID).innerText;